# In a loop: No module named 'conda'

Tags: python, pandas, miniconda

I am in a loop of problems.  If I try to install the latest version of miniconda, it fails with

```
/miniconda3/conda.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

I can successfully install miniconda 4.5.12. However, if I then run

conda install pandas

It fails with

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

The attempt breaks my miniconda.  Any attempts to use conda after that fail with

```
/miniconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
```

I am on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo).

Comment: What path did you use for miniconda?

Comment: @SublimizeD /usr1/jsmith/miniconda3  (The full error messages are actually like "path  /usr1/jsmith/miniconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory".)  When I execute the command conda install pandas , however, it is from a different directory, 
/yesbb_gis_esri/monthlystats .

Answer (score 1):

Try `export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp; mkdir $TMPDIR` before installing conda.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple.  Install the version that did work,  4.5.12, then `conda update conda`.